# Assigning atomic number based on atomic symbol

Tags: c++, performance

I currently have the following code:

```
unsigned int symToZ(const std::string & sym){
    unsigned int atomicNum;
    if(sym == "H"){atomicNum = 1;}
    else if(sym == "He"){atomicNum = 2;}
    else if(sym == "Li"){atomicNum = 3;}
    else if(sym == "Be"){atomicNum = 4;}
    else if(sym == "B"){atomicNum = 5;}
    else if(sym == "C"){atomicNum = 6;}
    else if(sym == "N"){atomicNum = 7;}
    else if(sym == "O"){atomicNum = 8;}
    else if(sym == "F"){atomicNum = 9;}
    ...

    return atomicNum;
}
```

The code simply takes in a string `sym` (which is the atomic symbol, such as He, F, Au, and so on), and converts it to the respective atomic number. As you can see, it involves a lot of repeated code. For such simple code, I feel it is needlessly complex.

How can this be done more effectively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most efficient way is to use **`unordered_map`** since C++11:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> symbol_to_number = {
        {"H",  1},
        {"He", 2},
        {"Li", 3},
        // And so on..
    };

    // Usage:
    std::cout << symbol_to_number["H"] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Above, you get the number out of a symbol in constant time which improves on going through a lot of **`if`** statements.

Comment: Does this work for three different things, such as `{"H", 1, 1.008}`?

Comment: @Idempotence Not directly, but yes: you can wrap 1 and 1.008 into a [pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) and use it like a value for **`"H"`**.

Answer (score 2):

Use [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

```
unsigned int symToZ(const std::string& sym)
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> table = {
        {"He", 2}
      , {"Li", 3}
      , {"Be", 4}
      , {"B", 5}
      , {"C", 6}
      , {"N", 7}
      , {"O", 8}
      , {"F", 9}
    };

    return table[sym];
}
```

Notice that [operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) inserts elements if they do not already exist in the map.  If you do not want this behavior or you want to handle the error differently than returning a value-initialized unsigned int then do the following:

```
unsigned int symToZ(const std::string& sym)
{
    const std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> table = {
        {"He", 2}
      , {"Li", 3}
      , {"Be", 4}
      , {"B", 5}
      , {"C", 6}
      , {"N", 7}
      , {"O", 8}
      , {"F", 9}
    };

    auto it = table.find(sym);
    if (it != std::end(table))
    {
        return *it;
    }
    else
    {
        // some error
    }
}
```

Comment: That table needs to be static const unless you want to rebuild it for each conversion.

Answer (score 1):

This look like a typical case of mapping values to a key.

Enter [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
std::map<std::string,long double> atomic_num_map;
void init_map()
{
    atomic_num_map["He"] = 2;
    //and so on for all symbols
}
long double symToZ(const std::string & sym){
    auto i = atomic_num_map.find(sym);
    if(i != atomic_num_map.end())
        return *i.second;
    else
    {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

In most cases this will work but if you are really serious about performance there is another version ([std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) with [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound))

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string,long double>> atomic_num_map;
void init_map()
{
    atomic_num_map.push_back(std::pair<std::string,long double>("He",2));
    //and so on for all symbols

    std::sort(atomic_num_map.begin(),atomic_num_map.end(), [](const auto & a,const auto & b){
        return a.first < b.first;
    });
}
long double symToZ(const std::string & sym){
    auto i = std::lower_bound(atomic_num_map.begin(),atomic_num_map.end(), sym,[](const auto & a,const auto & b){
        return a.first < b;
    });
    if(i != atomic_num_map.end() && *i.first == sym)
        return *i.second;
    else
    {
        //return an error
    }
}
```

now this a lot faster, but if you need to go even faster there is one last thing that you can do, avoid using `std::string`.

option one, if your key string is not longer that 4 character, you can use ints as a key

```
atomic_num_map.push_back(std::pair<int,long double>('He',2));
atomic_num_map.push_back(std::pair<int,long double>('B', /*whatever value*/));
atomic_num_map.push_back(std::pair<int,long double>('O', /*whatever value*/)); //and so on
```

option two is to use a [hash function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)

Important node: don't forget to handle the case where you have invalid strings. You might also want to consider converting the string to a lower case to avoid case mismatches